# Why this code is not showing the background image on svg rectangale

Tags: html, css, svg

My code below is not working as expected. Not showing the image in the background of the rectangle.

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="600" height="700">
      <rect width="300" height="400" class="eq__NEcontainer__currentAlarmAction" style="fill:url(#godhelpme);">
        <title stroke="blue">My test</title>
      </rect>
      <defs id="godhelpme">
        <pattern width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0" patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <image width="200" height="200" class="eq__NEcontainer__currentAlarmAction" xlink:href="CurrentList.png"></image>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```

The rectangle is always black as in the image. Any ideas ?[image]. I have tried debugging using chrome. In the debugger clicking on the image tag shows empty. I have attached the images for reference.[image: image tag in chrome debugger][image: Blank image container without image]. Any help would be of greatly appreciated.

Comment: uh, your CSS tag seems irrelevant without code.

Comment: Remove class from the image and see what is hapening?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot reference a <defs> element as the fill, you want the <pattern>. So put the `id` on the <pattern> element instead. Also in general you should aim to put your <defs> elements before where they're used, it's more efficient that way.

Like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <svg width="600" height="700">
      <defs>
        <pattern id="godhelpme" width="200" height="200" x="0" y="0" 
                 patternUnits="userSpaceOnUse">
          <image width="200" height="200" 
                 class="eq__NEcontainer__currentAlarmAction" 
                 xlink:href="CurrentList.png"></image>
        </pattern>
      </defs>
      <rect width="300" height="400" class="eq__NEcontainer__currentAlarmAction"
            style="fill:url(#godhelpme);">
        <title stroke="blue">My test</title>
      </rect>
    </svg>
  </body>
</html>
```